# Rearrange names from different rows in the same column

Tags: excel, rows, calculated-columns

I copy names from the website and paste them in an Excel worksheet, but they don't paste right after each other. There are blank cells spacing every name from the next one.

Is there a way to get them arranged, instead of moving each name to the next one?

[image]

Comment: Sort them after pasting.

Comment: And or remove duplicates (if only the blanks are repeating).

Comment: But how? I want an automatic way to do that? Is sorting enough?

Comment: Can you post the website url? Maybe the pasting part is the problem. You can try different paste special options.

Comment: I figured it out, I learned a technique by selecting the area and then I click on F5 and goto advanced and select blanks then delete the blank cells.

Answer (score 1):

Select the area and then click on <kbd>F5</kbd>. From the go to window, write the range of cells and select advanced. Select blanks and choose the type of delete you want to delete the blank cells.